# How to connect Nokia Lumia 610 to Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4

Tags: lumia, zune, phone-connector-mac, nokia-lumia-610

I am trying to connect my Nokia Lumia 610 to my Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4, however the mac is not recognising its plugged in , and the phone is not showing its connected either (charging but not recognised as media device).

Videos on youtube say to download windows phone connector from the mac app store, however according to my search results it no longer exists. any information regarding an alternative to connect the two would be greatly appreciated,

thanks.

Comment: Can you also add what Phone OS version you're running on the device (find it in under the About > More Info) in Settings

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are no Windows Phone Clients for Mac OS. If you have wifi access, you could try using [Feem](http://tryfeem.com/en/download.html) , it is available for almost every OS, on PC and Phone.

Or

You could also use [Xender](http://www.xender.com) app on your mobile and open [Xender Web](http://web.xender.com/) on any browser on your Mac